# laravel-mix / webpack, ignore sass loaded file (font) to be exported

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, css-loader, sass-loader

I am trying to skip a dependency loaded font (with `url()` ) to be exported.
I used [ignore-loader](https://github.com/cherrry/ignore-loader/) module.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /context-menu-icons\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'ignore-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

The issue is it produce empty files. The behavior I am expecting is to not output these files at all.

[image: mix compile outputs empty files]
[image]

The reason for this is this in a dependency in node_modules

```
@font-face {
  font-family: '#{$context-menu-icon-font-name}';
  src: url('#{$context-menu-icon-font-path}#{$context-menu-icon-font-name}.eot?#{$context-menu-icons-cachebust}');
  src: url('#{$context-menu-icon-font-path}#{$context-menu-icon-font-name}.eot?#{$context-menu-icons-cachebust}#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('#{$context-menu-icon-font-path}#{$context-menu-icon-font-name}.woff2?#{$context-menu-icons-cachebust}') format('woff2'),
  url('#{$context-menu-icon-font-path}#{$context-menu-icon-font-name}.woff?#{$context-menu-icons-cachebust}') format('woff'),
  url('#{$context-menu-icon-font-path}#{$context-menu-icon-font-name}.ttf?#{$context-menu-icons-cachebust}') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Is there a way to just ignore these files from output / copy in my dist folder ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution because, font-face is loaded from a scss file.
So using options with `file-loader` to prevent emitting files won't work.
There would be a string in these file with `module.exports = ...`

In all cases the font files would be emmited empty or not.

So I used [clean-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin) with these options

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
...
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            // dry: true,
            verbose: true,
            // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false,
            // Do not allow removal of current webpack assets
            protectWebpackAssets: false,
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [
                '**/*', // clean all
                '!views','!views/**/*', // ignore views folder
                '!lang','!lang/**/*',  // ignore lang folder
            ],
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: [
                'fonts/vendor' // remove fonts/vendor folder after build and watch
            ],
        }),
    ]
});
...
```